# MapKit Фильтр или Как вывести только отели на карте?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

У меня возник вопрос **Как вывести только отели на карте?** Мне нужно чтобы на карте выводилось не все, там магазины, **а только отели**, как это можно сделать? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее:

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Hotels"
request.region = mapView.region

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in
    guard let response = response else {
        print("Search error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    for item in response.mapItems {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Больше информации [тут](http://nshipster.com/mklocalsearch/).

Comment: Тут response.mapItems - это массив в котором мои отели с базы?

Comment: Извините, но вот еще такой вопрос, а что должно быть после прохода по циклу **for**? Я просто не понимаю, как оно выведется на карте?

Comment: response.mapItems это массив ваших отелей. Раз Вы не до конца поняли тему, почитайте документацию или туториалы, надо разобраться и понять.